# Which site must I use to ask questions about EEG?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have questions related to EEG (electroencephalogram) which is used to measure brain signals, which site of Stack Exchange can be used to ask questions about EEG? I want to ask questions related to visualization, interpretation and based on time series properties of the EEG signals?

Comment: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eeg https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electroencephalography https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eeg All three of these sites have a tag for it, check their help sections and see which one best fits your question. To me, Biology seems to fit well but i'm no expert.

Comment: all have questions related to my interest thanks for the help

Comment: can I have a single site which combines the questions specifically based on eeg

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to combine questions from multiple sites, you could suggest a new site but without a pre built community to back it, it probably won't get anywhere. https://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "can I have a single site which combines the questions specifically based on eeg" Just think of Stackexchange as as a single site maybe? What do you want to do with the combination of all questions tagged EEG?

Comment: If it specifically about the statistical analysis of time series then https://stats.stackexchange.com/ might be appropriate. There certainly have been questions about EEG analysis there.